# Dice Roller Change Sides and Amount of Dice in Set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, dice

I am creating a dice roller that allows users to change the amount of sides on the dice as well as change the amount of dice in a set. I am able to get a console output, but not the right output within my HTML page. Ideally, when you click the button, it will change the amount of sides on the dice as well as the amount of dice. I would like to know what I am doing wrong, and how I would go about fixing it! Thanks!!!

```js
numbers = [
  "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50"
]

$(function() {
  //var dice;
  // For creating a new Diceset
  dice = new DiceSet();

  $("#rollButton").click(function() {
    //var dice, outcomeList, message;
    outcomeList = dice.roll();
    console.log(outcomeList);

    // a good start, but you really don't want to reference //the array this way

    // use a for loop here instead of outcomeList

    message = "Rolled Dice!  " + outcomeList + " <br>";
    $("#outcome").append(message);
  });

  // place click handler for reset here
  $("#diceResetButton").click(function() {
    dice.reset();
    $("#outcome").html("");
    console.log("Reset is Supposed to happen...")
  });
  //click handler for changing the number of sides
  $("#setDiceSetSidesButton").click(function() {
    var select, chosen_number;
    dice.setNumSides(6);
    chosen_number = numbers[select];
    $("DiceSize").html(chosen_number);
    console.log("Amount of Sides on Dice Should Change...")
  });

  // click handler for setting the number of dice in the diceset 
  $("#setDiceSetSizeButton").click(function() {
    var select, chosen_number;
    dice.setDiceSetSize(2);
    chosen_number = numbers[select];
    $("DiceSides").html(chosen_number);
    console.log("Dice Set Amount Should change...")
  });

  // click handler for getting the average number of rolls
  $("#RollAverageButton").click(function() {
    dice.getAverage();
    console.log("Average is Supposed to Be Displayed...")
  });

});
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>  
  <h1>Dice Roller Simulation</h1>
  <input type="number" id="setDiceSetSize" value="2" id="DiceSize" />
  <input type="button" id="setDiceSetSizeButton" value="Set Dice Size" />
  <br>
  
  <input type="number" id="setDiceSetSides" value="6" id="DiceSides">
  <input type="button" id="setDiceSetSidesButton" value="Set Amount of Sides on Dice" />
  <p> <input type="button" id="rollButton" value="Roll Dice" /> </p>
  <p> <input type="button" id="RollAverageButton" value="Get Average" /> </p>
  <p><input type="button" id="diceResetButton" value="Reset Dice Roll" /> </p>

  <p id="outcome"> </p>
```

```js
//
// Example use:
//   dice = new DiceSet();
//
//   dice.roll() --> simulates roll and returns array of individual dice results
//   dice.numRolls() --> number of times the set of dice has been rolled
//   dice.getAverage() --> average totals from the sets
//   dice.history --> an array of totals from the set rolls
//
//   dice.reset() --> resets history of dice rolls
//
//   dice.setNumSides(8) --> configure for 8-sided DiceSet
//   dice.setDiceSetSize(4) --> roll 4 dice with each set


class DiceSet {
  constructor() {
    this.sides = 6;
    this.quantity = 2;
    this.history = [];
    this.runningTotal = 0;
  }

  singleRoll() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides + 1);
  }

  setNumSides(numSides) {
    this.sides = numSides;
    this.reset();
  }

  setDiceSetSize(numDice) {
    this.quantity = numDice;
    this.reset();
  }

  reset() {
    this.history = [];
    this.runningTotal = 0;
  }

  numRolls() {
    return this.history.length;
  }

  getAverage() {
    return this.runningTotal / this.history.length;
  }

  roll() {
    var total, same, rollSet, i;
    same = true;
    rollSet = [];
    rollSet[0] = this.singleRoll();
    total = rollSet[0];
    for (i = 1; i < this.quantity; i++) {
      rollSet[i] = this.singleRoll();
      total += rollSet[i];
      if (rollSet[i] !== rollSet[i - 1]) {
        same = false;
      }
    }
    this.history.push(total);
    this.runningTotal += total;
    return rollSet;


  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an array of numbers? Can't you just do toString?

Comment: @SheshankShankar I was fairly certain I was using the array incorrectly. How would I go about implementing the toString?

Comment: You don't need to implement it, check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString

Comment: @SheshankShankar Thank you, that actually really helped! Would you happen to know about how to get the average of the rolls that would be displayed on the screen?

Comment: Yup, I think you can just use a for loop, add them all together and divide by the number of times the for loop iterated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/cCrul/8mof1hk4/

```js
//
// Example use:
//   dice = new DiceSet();
//
//   dice.roll() --> simulates roll and returns array of individual dice results
//   dice.numRolls() --> number of times the set of dice has been rolled
//   dice.getAverage() --> average totals from the sets
//   dice.history --> an array of totals from the set rolls
//
//   dice.reset() --> resets history of dice rolls
//
//   dice.setNumSides(8) --> configure for 8-sided DiceSet
//   dice.setDiceSetSize(4) --> roll 4 dice with each set


class DiceSet {
  constructor() {
    this.sides = 6;
    this.quantity = 2;
    this.history = [];
    this.runningTotal = 0;
  }

  singleRoll() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides + 1);
  }

  setNumSides(numSides) {
    this.sides = numSides;
    this.reset();
  }

  setDiceSetSize(numDice) {
    this.quantity = numDice;
    this.reset();
  }

  reset() {
    this.history = [];
    this.runningTotal = 0;
  }

  numRolls() {
    return this.history.length;
  }

  getAverage() {
    return this.runningTotal / this.history.length;
  }

  roll() {
    var total, same, rollSet, i;
    same = true;
    rollSet = [];
    rollSet[0] = this.singleRoll();
    total = rollSet[0];
    for (i = 1; i < this.quantity; i++) {
      rollSet[i] = this.singleRoll();
      total += rollSet[i];
      if (rollSet[i] !== rollSet[i - 1]) {
        same = false;
      }
    }
    this.history.push(total);
    this.runningTotal += total;
    return rollSet;
  }
}

numbers = [
  "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50"
]

$(function() {
  //var dice;
  // For creating a new Diceset
  dice = new DiceSet();


  $("#rollButton").click(function() {
    //var dice, outcomeList, message;
    outcomeList = dice.roll();
    console.log(outcomeList);

    // a good start, but you really don't want to reference //the array this way

    // use a for loop here instead of outcomeList

    message = "Rolled Dice!  " + outcomeList + " <br>";
    $("#outcome").append(message);
  });


  // place click handler for reset here
  $("#diceResetButton").click(function() {
    dice.reset();
    $("#outcome").html("");
    console.log("Reset is Supposed to happen...")
  });
  
  //click handler for changing the number of sides
  $("#setDiceSetSidesButton").click(function() {
    var chosen_number = $("#setDiceSetSides").val();
    dice.setNumSides(chosen_number);
    $("DiceSize").html(chosen_number);
    console.log("Amount of Sides on Dice Should Change...")
  });


  // click handler for setting the number of dice in the diceset 
  $("#setDiceSetSizeButton").click(function() {
    var chosen_number = $("#setDiceSetSize").val();
    dice.setDiceSetSize(chosen_number);
    $("DiceSides").html(chosen_number);
    console.log("Dice Set Amount Should change...")
  });

  // click handler for getting the average number of rolls
  $("#RollAverageButton").click(function() {
    alert(dice.getAverage());
    console.log("Average is Supposed to Be Displayed...")
  });

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Dice Demo</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">

    </script>
    <script src="dice.js"></script>
    <script src="diceLS.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Dice Roller Simulation</h1>
    <input type="number" id="setDiceSetSize" value="2" id="DiceSize">
    <input type="button" id="setDiceSetSizeButton" value="Set Dice Size" />
    <br>
    <input type="number" id="setDiceSetSides" value="6" id="DiceSides">
    <input type="button" id="setDiceSetSidesButton" value="Set Amount of Sides on Dice" />
    <p> <input type="button" id="rollButton" value="Roll Dice" /> </p>
    <p> <input type="button" id="RollAverageButton" value="Get Average" /> </p>
    <p><input type="button" id="diceResetButton" value="Reset Dice Roll" /> </p>
    <p id="outcome"> </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was looking to achieve!

Comment: Feel free to mark as solved ^_^, rep points are good for bounties.